# Overwrite storyboard Height and Width for UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I've been trying to design a reusable component for my app. It's principally for learning purposes.

I' trying to set constraints programmatically, but the `Interface Builder` keeps adding automatic constraints :

```
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fae02731800 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[_1.TOHeader:0x7fae02718c20(89)]>
```

Thats breaks mine.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class TOHeader: UIView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        println("init aDecoder")
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        self.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    }

    override func willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview: UIView?) {
        super.willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview)
        println("willMoveToSuperview()")
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        superview!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview!, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        superview!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview!, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 42))
    }


}
```

Comment: First you should add top constraint to you TOHeader.

Comment: Just tried adding this top constraint: `addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))`, it does make my app crash

Comment: Your top constraint doesn't have a relation between superview or other view try like that `superview!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview!, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))`

Comment: That does work out well, thanks. But the width and height constraints still aren't applied as they're breaked by the `Interface Builder` ones. Any thought ? Maybe there's a better way

Comment: Generally I would prefer adding constraints in superview not in the view. When you add TOHeader to your view you should add your constraints after called `addSubview:` method

Comment: My aim there was to provide an all-in-one component that can be reused as-is without more configuration

Comment: I see. But when I tried to implement reusable components, I wouldn't add constraints inside the component. Because things can be changed and this component can be used another places. For instance, if you add top constraint as I write below, it always add this view to your superview's top. It means you can't change in your superview and it loses it's reusability.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88981/discussion-between-whitep4nther-and-candost-dagdeviren).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the constraints in the storyboard. Then Ctrl drag on each of them from the View Hierarchy to the class to create outlets for them. You can then access and change them from within the code, see below in the viewDidLoad method

[image]

Comment: This is not what @whitep4nther asked.